# How to specify more than 1 url-path-map in the command of az network application-gateway rule create

Tags: azure, azure-cli

The command in question is this:

```
az network application-gateway rule create --gateway-name --name --resource-group [--address-pool] [--http-listener] [--http-settings] [--no-wait {0, 1, f, false, n, no, t, true, y, yes}] [--priority] [--redirect-config] [--rewrite-rule-set] [--rule-type {Basic, PathBasedRouting}] [--url-path-map]
```

I have 2 url-path-map named MyPathMap2 and MyPathMap3.

But if I want it to have 2 or more paths I do not know how to modify the command so that it accepts more than 1 path-map.

According to the documentation, I should use the parameter **--rule-type PathBasedRouting**, then to create the rule with 1 single path-map I use the command:

```
az network application-gateway rule create --gateway-name --name --resource-group --address-pool --http-listener --http-settings --rule-type PathBasedRouting --url-path-map MyPathMap2 --priority
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want it to have 2 or more paths I do not know how to modify the command so that it accepts more than 1 path-map.

AFAIK, we can't pass the 2 URL path-map while creating an application gateway network rule.

You can follow this **[MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-url-route-cli)** to create URL path map to add in the rule name.

You can create a single Url path map while creating an application gateway rule.

**Command:**

I have created a rule for a single URL path map with the below command.

```
az network application-gateway rule create \
  --gateway-name myAppGateway \
  --name rule2 \
  --resource-group myResourceGroupAG \
  --http-listener backendListener \
  --rule-type PathBasedRouting \
  --url-path-map myPathMap \
  --address-pool appGatewayBackendPool \
  --priority 200
```

**Output:**
[image]

If you need to add the Url path map with the same rule name, you can use the command below.

**Command:**

```
az network application-gateway url-path-map rule create \
  --gateway-name myAppGateway \
  --name videoPathRule \
  --resource-group myResourceGroupAG \
  --path-map-name myPathMap \
  --paths /video/* \
  --address-pool videoBackendPool \
  --http-settings appGatewayBackendHttpSettings
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: So in simple terms, if I want to create an appgateway rule and it has only 1 url-path-map, I should use az network application-gateway url-path-map create but if I am going to specify more than 1, I should almost by force use az network application-gateway url-path-map rule create together with az network application-gateway url-path-map?

Comment: Yes, after creating a single url path map you can use the `az network application-gateway url-path-map rule create`.